# Convert kecka256 hash string back to bytes32

Tags: solidity, keccak, bytes32

I am storing kecccak256 to hash some string value and store it as mapping.

```
 mapping(bytes32 => address) internal _owners;
```

and my mint function looks like this -

```
function _mint(address to, string calldata input) internal virtual {
        bytes32 tokenId = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(input));

        require(to != address(0), "ERC721: mint to the zero address");
        require(!_exists(tokenId), "ERC721: token already minted");

        unchecked {
            // Will not overflow unless all 2**256 token ids are minted to the same owner.
            // Given that tokens are minted one by one, it is impossible in practice that
            // this ever happens. Might change if we allow batch minting.
            // The ERC fails to describe this case.
            _balances[to] += 1;
        }

        _owners[tokenId] = to;

        emit Transfer(address(0), to, tokenId);
    }
```

It works well but when user specify string value of tokenId to check if the token exist or not, i need to convert it back to bytes32 which i am not able to do.

```
function _ownerOf(string calldata tokenId) internal view virtual returns (address) {
   bytes32 tokenIdInBytes32 = // need this code
   return _owners[tokenIdInBytes32];
}
```

Comment: You should change the _ownerOf signature to use bytes32 `_ownerOf(bytes32 tokenId)`.

Comment: ok thanks, that worked. I was thinking that i will have to convert into bytes32 manually in my code but seems like solidity is automatically converting.